# Veracrypt not unmounting volume when rebooting windows 10

Tags: windows, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I use Veracrypt with a 100gig encrypted volume. I find that this is a good solution on my laptop because if my laptop gets stolen the work is in an encrypted veracrypt volume and is protected. The thief won't gain access to my work/code, etc.

A disturbing trend I see recently is that when I reboot Windows 10, the Veracrypt volume is not unmounted and it comes back as if it was never dismounted. So, when I reboot windows 10 the volume is still mounted as a drive, making the use of the encrypted volume useless. :( - The way it used to work is that I would have to manually mount the volume with Veracrypt (provide password and mount)

This happens intermittently when I reboot Windows 10. Maybe Windows 10 and its updates have something to do with it? Maybe Windows 10 makes you think you are rebooting it but it somehow has some sneaky sleep thing built into it in recent versions? I've been through the veracrypt settings but cannot find a setting to remedy this. Veracrypt is set to 'never save history'.

Anybody know a fix for this or a Veracrypt substitute that works like Veracrypt where this kind of thing does not happen?

Comment: I'm sure you know that you can dismount any VC volume before rebooting and I understand you don't do that because convenience. But convinience is often the enemy of safety/privacy. That said, you probably should disable the fast startup feature that is enabled by default since Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a script that is executed when Windows is shut down:

Create the script, for example a .cmd-File:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\Veracrypt" /q /w /f /d u
```

It starts the program in the default path with the following parameters:
/q - quiet, no display
/w - wipe cache
/f - force
/d - dismount Volume U:

Now the script must only be linked to the shutdown:

Execute gpedit.msc (local Policies)
Computer Configuration -> Windows settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown -> Properties -> Add